# Multiple tmux prefix key combos?

Tags: tmux

I've got tmux setup just the way I like it, and my chosen key of prefix is `, because it's so quick and easy to use.

Everything was gravy until I tried using tmux from my phone, which doesn't have a ` key. Is there anyway to additionally bind ^a to the prefix, so I can use *BOTH* combos at the same time?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Starting with *tmux* 1.6, you can use the session option `prefix2` to specify a second prefix key (e.g. in `~/.tmux.conf`):

```
set-option -g prefix `
set-option -g prefix2 C-a
```

Note: If you have any bindings or script that use the `send-prefix`, you can use its `-2` option to send the key assigned to `prefix2`:  `send-prefix -2`.

Prior to *tmux* 1.6, the `prefix` option accepted a comma-separated list of keys:

```
set-option -g prefix `,C-a
```

Comment: very useful answer, both working under tmux 1.5 and 1.6 : thanks !