# Change (or disable) tmux prefix in session basis

Tags: tmux

I am wondering if there is a way to temporary change tmux prefix depending on the active session.

I manage multiple sessions with tmux to work in different tasks or projects in my local desktop. But I sometimes need to work on remote systems where it is also useful to open multiple panes, windows or even distinct sessions.

Opening a remote tmux session inside my local tmux works fine, but I need to press the prefix key twice (I have a map to send itself on double press) every time I want to issue a (remote) tmux command.

This is very annoying because most times I end up sending it to my local tmux unintentionally.

If I could change local prefix *only* for a given session (or, at least, while that session is active) it would be wonderful.

Temporary disabling it also could be enought because [I can define an alternate prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10148449/multiple-tmux-prefix-key-combos) to use it only when my primary one is disabled.

Any suggestion will be welcomed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I answer myself:

It is as easy as not specifying the `-g` modifier in the `set prefix` command.

For example, in my case that my usual prefix is <kbd>tab</kbd> key, to use regular <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> prefix in the current session:

```
[tab]:set prefix C-b
```